# SharePoint 2013 search shows incorrect version of document

Tags: sharepoint-search

When we search for document in SharePoint it shows incorrect document version that is 8.1 when the document is sitting at 9.0  version, this document is check in and approved though it shows incorrect. when I click and try to open it then it is opening correct version of document(9.0). Can you please assist me with this. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The Rev 8.1 version is just a string of text inside the document that SharePoint Search has indexed. It is not at all related to SharePoint version numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Search is just displaying the data as it got them when it indexed the content.

I assume that the text you're highlighting is a quick part showing the version number.

What happens is then the following.

1. A user checks out and edits a draft version of the document (8.1)
2. Word updates the quick part to show this version (8.1)
3. At some point the document is approved (now version 9.0)
4. But the text isn't really changed so when search indexes the document it sees the draft version in the text (8.1)
5. When you open the document word gets the updated version (9.0) and updates the text, so you see the updated version (9.0), but search never sees this as part of the text, only as the document property.

Unfortunately there is no way to change the text crawled to be up to date if it's the SharePoint version number you use.

Here is a couple of other solution (just out of my head and not tested):

1. Use another column in the quick part, could be calculated to be x.0 if approved and (x+1.0) when in draft
2. Change display template to show Managed Property with version number

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It makes sense. Can you please advise what should I do in order to show correct one, If I reset search index and run full crawl does it resolve this issue?.

Comment: Unfortunately there really isn't anything you can do to get the updated text because it'll not be stored until you change the document, but then it won't be 9.0 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please crawl your content again , this would be resolved. as Per Jakobsen correctly put the reason .

The content would not have crawled at that time, but actually content changed post crawl.